# How does CloudRun in GCP coverts http 1.1 to http 2 for flask application

Tags: flask, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, gcp-load-balancer

We have API's that are written in Flask application and by default flask only supports http 1.1 unless we use some reverse proxy like Nginx. I was experimenting to check if Classic Application Load balancer could act as a reverse proxy for our use cause so that we could directly use flask application on Gunicorn and then deploy it on a CloudRun. Then this CloudRun is used as a backend for a HTTPS Classic LoadBalancer.

When docker image was ran locally I could see that the API's were using http 1.1 protocol but when it was deployed on Load balancer I could see that it was using http 2 protocol. Then I checked the http resource from the Cloudrun instance and the API's were using http 2 protocol. How does this actually get converted from http1.1 to http2? Can someone help me understand this mechanism ?

Image 1 is deployed in Local
[image: Local deployment of]

Image 2 is deployed in HTTP Classic load balancer without CDN
[image: Deployed on the Load balancer]

Image 3 is deployed on CloudRun
[image: Deployed on Cloudrun]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP 1.1 is not converted to HTTP 2. The client includes an upgrade header in the request. If the server supports HTTP 2, it responds with a “101 Switching” status and then uses HTTP 2 on that connection.

More details are provided [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Upgrade).

Cloud Run HTTP 2 Details:

> For Cloud Run services, Cloud Run by default downgrades HTTP/2
> requests to HTTP/1 when those requests are sent to the container. If you want to explicitly set your service to use HTTP/2 end-to-end, with no such downgrading, you can configure it for HTTP/2.

[Cloud Run: Using HTTP/2 (services)](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/http2)

Comment: Is there something else with HTTPS Load balancer and proxying? I mean, your browser can communicate in HTTP/2 with the load balancer, and the load balancer proxy the connection and open a new HTTP/1 connection with Cloud Run. Maybe it's wrong, not sure... In addition, I read somewhere that internal traffic at google was HTTP/2 and the HTTP/1 traffic wrapped in that standard HTTP/2 internal protocol

Comment: If i add nginx to this python application will it improve the response time of api's ?

Comment: Adding a layer rarely increases the response time! So, no. The difference is about sub-millisecond. It's important when you handle millions/billions of request, like Google. But I think you should have other bottleneck before looking at the network layer (especially Python is one slow piece in your design!)

Comment: @sidharthvijayakumar - Maybe, but I doubt it. Cloud Run already has a front end to proxy requests. Adding Nginx would just add another network layer. Another item is that HTTP/2 in the container rarely improves Cloud Run performance except in particular use cases. You may be chasing a solution for which there is no problem that needs solving.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere - when you connect to most load balancers (reverse proxy), the connection is terminated at the load balancer. The load balancer then opens a new connection to the backend. Each connection can use HTTP/1 or HTTP/2 if supported. There are also pass-through load balancers where the connection terminates at the backend. The exact details depend on the load balancer and configuration. One easy method to determine proxy versus pass-through is to look at the source IP address. Proxies have the load balancer as the source IP address. Pass-through has the client's IP address.

Comment: @JohnHanley thank you those points are informative. My load balancers has the IP of load balancer not the client as the ip